# How to rotate montly backups of automysqlbackup script?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, backup

I just discovered all automysqlbackup are rotated but monthly backup are keeped forever. Is there any chance to rotate the montly backups too?

I'm using the default distribution of Ubuntu 64bit 20.04

Comment: Probably. But you have to include information about your configuration and environment.

Comment: yes, sorry, I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different approach, using zpaq.
You can find Debian (updated) for sure (I do not use Ubuntu) or directly from the author's website http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html

You will get a single file with all the SQL you want, stored inside, optionally encrypted.
No need to rotate anything, keeps the data forever